# How do I put array elements into a HTML table?

Tags: ruby

```
array = ["abc","mohasdan","321","324324"]
recipients = ["xxx@example.com"]
recipients_formatted = []
recipients.each {|s| recipients_formatted << "To: #{s}"}
message = <<MESSAGE_END
From: xxx@example.com <xxx@example.com>
#{recipients_formatted}

MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: Chef Report
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table {border-collapse:collapse;}
table, td, th {border:1px solid black;padding:5px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Chef Check-in Report</h2>
<p>
<p>
<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>Node</th>
<th>Time Since Last Check-in (Mins)</th>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
MESSAGE_END

Net::SMTP.start('localhost') do |smtp|
smtp.send_message message, 'xxx@example.com',
                           recipients
end
```

The above code sends an email containing a table somthing like this:

```
Chef  (column1)      |  Check-in Report(column2)   (row 1)
```

I put the array content into the table which is to be sent through email.
I want the first array element in the first column of row one, the second array element in the second column of row one.
The third array element in the first column of row two, the fourth array element in the second column of row two, and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try something like this:

```
custom_rows = ""
array.each_slice(2) do |row| 
  custom_rows << "<tr><td>#{row[0]}</td><td>#{row[1]}</td></tr>"
end
```

Than inside your `message` put `#{custom_rows}`:

```
message = <<MESSAGE_END
From: xxx@example.com <xxx@example.com>
#{recipients_formatted}

MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: Chef Report
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table {border-collapse:collapse;}
table, td, th {border:1px solid black;padding:5px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Chef Check-in Report</h2>
<p>
<p>
<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>Node</th>
<th>Time Since Last Check-in (Mins)</th>
</tr>
#{custom_rows}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Missing the interpolation operator #{}.

Comment: Thanks @AnatoliyKukuland  .. But anything that i put after message = <<MESSAGE_END gets embedded as html .. I dont know how to differentiate ruby code from html , while building the email body

Comment: @AnatoliyKukul : "my_array.each_slice(2) do |row| " goes in as html content too . So it says undefined "row" .. if i put it above message = <<MESSAGE_END , it asks for end statement

Comment: @AnatoliyKukul : Thanks a ton Boss .. Your edited code helped me ... Cheers !